# List of confirmed working Nvidia cards

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 16.04, compatibility

Is there a crowd-sourced list of Nvidia cards which are confirmed to actually work on Ubuntu with the proprietary Nvidia drivers?

A matrix of Ubuntu version, Nvidia model and whether they work with nouveau, Nvidia or both would be useful when shopping for cards.

I currently have a gforce 210 and despite it being listed as supported by the drivers, I was never able to get it to work on the Nvidia drivers though it worked with poor performance under nouveau. I am hoping to find one that will work "as expected" under 16.04 LTS - meaning I can just pick the proprietary driver in the system settings and reboot and it will work - not super interested in spending 3 hours hand-tooling `config` files, rebuilding packages and twiddling drivers - I do that for a day job :)

Thanks for reading...

Comment: Well what didn't work? NVIDIA and Ubuntu always have trouble, no matter the card.

Comment: @Zacharee1 But AMD`does it even better, their cards straight forward refuse to work.

Comment: @Videonauth we don't talk about AMD. They are dead to us.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I was hesitating on getting an AMD laptop a while back, can you explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: The processor isn't necessarily bad, but AMD's graphics division seems to be doing its best to not provide Linux with proper support. Cards that are as new as 2 years old sometimes have sudden end-of-lives. The new driver for 16.04 that may or may not be coming out barely supports the newest of the newest cards.